# how to add a new linkedlist element into arraylist

Tags: linked-list

Im new at Kava, and Im having a trouble to understand what am I doing wrong, and why my code isnt working.

Im trying to implement the bucket sort, using a given array of doubles (double[] ar), 
and using arrayList of linkedLists.

here is my code:

```
        int n = ar.length; 

    //initializing the buckets 
    ArrayList<LinkedList<Double>> buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Double>>(ar.length);

    // Initialize 'n' buckets (each is a LinkedList<Double>) (B[0..n-1])
    for (int i = 0; i < n -1; i++) {
        buckets.add(i, new LinkedList<Double>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    buckets.add((int)(n*ar[i]), ar[i]);
    }
```

it
shows an error on "add", and it says:
"The method add(int, LinkedList) in the type ArrayList> is not applicable for the arguments (int, double)"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<LinkedList<Double>> buckets[]` is your Array of ArrayList OF LinkedList Of DOUBLE.

You are addind a DOUBLE to your ArrayList insted of a LinkedList when doing :

```
buckets[(int)(n * ar[i])].add((Double)ar[i]);
```

Consider changing your buckets declaration

Maybe what you wanted is

```
 "ArrayList<Double> buckets[]"
```

But careful the instanciation changes to

```
buckets[index] = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Comment: Ok I changed the code, please look again, Im still having this kind of trouble

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    buckets.add((int)(n*ar[i]), ar[i]);
    }

This is wrong.  ar[i] is of type double and you are adding it to buckets witch requires to add LinkedList to it. 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   buckets.get((int)(n*ar[i])).addLast(ar[i]);
}